# Loop through worksheets in current workbook

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel, vsto

I am trying to loop through all of the worksheets inside of an active workbook when the user clicks a button on the ribbon.

The only issue I am having is actually iterating through the worksheets, I have the following error:

> Expression is of type 'Workbook', which is not a collection type.

While I understand what that means, I don't know how to actually achieve what I want.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim wks As Worksheet, objList As ListObject

    For Each wks In Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook  ' ERROR LINE

        For Each objList In wks.ListObjects
            objList.Unlist()
        Next objList

    Next wks
End Sub
```

** **UPDATE** **
Edited the code per the comments and answer, but it gives me a new error

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ConvertAllTablesToRange.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{297DC8D9-EABD-45A1-BDEF-68AB67E5C3C3}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: @chrisneilsen except now I get an exception `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet'. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` is the collection you're looking for.

Comment: @Adjit I prefer to use `.Sheets` as it is the bigger collection and will contain things like charts, but if you ONLY need to iterate through the worksheets and can ignore charts etc, then use `.Worksheets`. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Well, now I am getting an exception - `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet'. `

Comment: @Adjit What happens when you use `.Sheets`?